# Excel Exporting Arabic English mix text to CSV file contains Question Marks

Tags: excel, csv, text, utf-8, arabic

When I export an Excel spreadsheet that contains a mix of Arabic and English characters to CSV, the resultant file contains question marks instead of the Arabic text

Comment: Use Google SpreadSheets

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this was because Excel is not exporting the file as UTF-8. Unfortunately to do so, I had to install Open Office which lets you select the encoding type when saving an Excel spreadsheet as CSV. Hence I was able to select UTF-8 from a drop down.
The resultant file now even in Notepad, shows the correct mixture of Arabic and English characters.

Answer (score -3):

Another way to set the encoding is to do the following:

1. File->Save as
2. Beside the Save button there should be a 'Tools' dropdown button
3. Click and select "Web Options"
4. Select the "Encoding" tab and from the list of encodings select "Unicode (UTF-8)"

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't save in UTF-8.

Comment: I had the UTF-8 option but it didn't work sadly

Comment: It didn't work for me too!

Comment: Doesn't work for me either

Comment: its not working